# Arguments to variables during definition

Tags: c++, oop

I'm a C programmer who's trying to take baby steps in C++ and Object oriented programming. I came across the following syntax and I couldn't completely wrap my head around it - why does a variable have arguments here when defining it?

`unique_ptr<int> myvar(new int);`

I understand that `unique_ptr` takes a raw pointer as argument for its constructor, but what's the rationale of this syntax? Is this a syntax introduced later than C++98?

**EDIT:**

What I find particularly confusing is having a parentheses immediately following a new variable name. To me - this is how functions are declared. At first I thought the code declares a function named `myvar` but I knew that's probably wrong.

How's this different from a syntax similar to C or C++98? Is there a name for this type of syntax?

Comment: Those arguments get passed to the class' constructor. A constructor may take more than one parameter. What other syntax would you use for that? This syntax has been used since before C++98, the first standard.

Comment: `unique_ptr` was introduced in the c++11 standard

Comment: If you mean this `<int>` then you are looking for [template parameters and template arguments](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/template_parameters)

Comment: *To me - this is how functions are declared.* And this has caused a great deal of confusion for people and compilers alike. See [The Most Vexing Parse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Most_vexing_parse) for an extreme example.

Comment: @user4581301 Thank you for that link. Starting to make a lot more sense now

Comment: Unrelated: When compiling for the C++14 or later standards [prefer to use `std::make_unique`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr/make_unique) as it eliminates some potentially nasty problems with exceptions thrown during construction.

Answer (score 3):

No, this syntax has always been part of C++. It is used to initialize an object. A simpler example:

```
int a(1); // a == 1
```

> what's the rationale of this syntax?

I don't know, but if I had to guess it's because it looks like a call to the constructor<sup>1</sup>.

```
struct X {
    X(int); // looks like a function
};

X x(10); // looks like a call to the constructor
```

---

<sup>1</sup>: *Looks* like. You can't actually call a constructor.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. So the `new int` is just setting the initial value of the variable? In this case, can you rewrite it using multiple lines? like `int x = 5;` can be rewritten as `int x; x = 5;`. Or is it more nuanced than that?

Comment: @tomol Yes you can imagine it like that, but for class types, there is no initial value. It is more nuanced. For example, you can't do that in your case but if you had initialized your unique_ptr with another object of type unique_ptr, then it would have worked. It all depends on what assignment operator the class has.

Comment: @tomol difference is that in first case object is constructed and initialized with given initializer. In second case object is constructed and default-initialized (by call to default constructor if that is a class-type object, by zero-initialization if that's process-wide object or left with undetermined value). After that assignment is performed.